# In PDF format syntax should number 1.e10 be written as 10000000000.?

Tags: pdf, biginteger, specifications

Looking at the [PDF Referene ver 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) about how objects of type **number** 
are writen according to valid syntax it informs.

> Note: PDF does not support the PostScript syntax for numbers with
>   nondecimal radices (such as 16#FFFE ) or in exponential format (such
>   as 6.02E23 ).

However it also does not mandate a maximum range the numbers should be in. This seems to suggest it would be correct to write

`1.00E10` as `10000000000`

or

`1.00E-50` as `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

This question has hence 2 aspects:

- a) is the notation correct (as provided in the examples?
- b) does pdf format expect implementations to use (or at least fall back
  to some bigint/bigfloat handling) of numbers, as it seems to not provide
  any range for the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for normative information on PDF you should refer to the appropriate ISO standards, in particular ISO 32000. Yes, Part 1 (ISO 32000-1) in particular is derived from the PDF reference 1.7 without that many changes, but not without changes either. (Ok, in some situations one has to consult the old PDF reference, too, to understand some of these changes.)

Adobe has published a copy thereof (with "ISO" in the page headers removed) on its web site: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Now to your question:

According to ISO 32000, both part 1 and 2:

> An integer shall be written as one or more decimal digits optionally preceded by a sign. [...]
>
> A real value shall be written as one or more decimal digits with an optional sign and a leading, trailing, or embedded PERIOD (2Eh) (decimal point).

*(section 7.3.3 "Numeric Objects")*

Thus, concerning your question a)

> is the notation correct (as provided in the examples?

Yes, `10000000000` is an integer valued numeric object, `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` is a real valued numeric object.

Concerning your question b)

> does pdf format expect implementations to use (or at least fall back to some bigint/bigfloat handling) of numbers, as it seems to not provide any range for the numbers?

No, in the same section as quoted above you also find

> The range and precision of numbers may be limited by the internal representations used in the computer on which the conforming reader is running; Annex C gives these limits for typical implementations.

and Annex C recommends at least the following limits:

> **integer**
>   2,147,483,647
>   *Largest integer value; equal to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1.*
>
> **integer**
>   -2,147,483,648
>   *Smallest integer value; equal to −2<sup>31</sup>*
>
> **real**
>   ±3.403 × 10<sup>38</sup>
>   *Largest and smallest real values (approximate).*
>
> **real**
>   ±1.175 × 10<sup>-38</sup>
>   *Nonzero real values closest to 0 (approximate). Values closer than these are automatically converted to 0.*
>
> **real**
>   5
>   *Number of significant decimal digits of precision in fractional part (approximate).*

*(ISO 32000-1)*

> **Integers**
>   Integer values (such as object numbers) can often be expressed within 32 bits.
>
> **Real numbers**
>   Modern computers often represent and process real numbers using IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) single or double precision.

*(ISO 32000-2)*

Comment: so your answer confirms that for expressing  `1.00E-37`, which is suggested to be in the supported range the value in the PDF syntax should be correctly expressed as this string `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001`.  (also many thanks for inserting the reference to the other standards, I was not aware about the 1.7 reference being partly outdated)

Comment: @humanityANDpeace You can even continue expressing 1E-50 as in your question, you merely have to be aware that it will very likely be treated as zero by PDF processors.

Comment: because of `1E-50` being outside of the safe range. Anyway what I have a challange to grasp, or what seems so to me is to have to use the lengthy notation. There is no change to use a notation alike `1e-50` or `1e50`, but it would always have to be a string token with more or less ~53 characters (in case there is a decimal seperator and sign).

Comment: @humanityANDpeace It's always the lengthy notation, yes. But that's not that bad, on one hand you usually hardly ever need so small or large numbers, and on the other hand such sequences of zeros usually can be well compressed (if in a stream).

Comment: @mki I understand, mainly for those rare cases of big numbers the notation  seems simply very *unusual* / odd, which prompted me to ask this question, thinking I might have understood it not completely. But as it seems now, it is as I first though: `0000000000000000000000000000000000001` is PDF's syntax for `1.00E-37`, I now know without any remaining doubt! thank you mki